# Javascript/JQuery save form fields in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a from with several text inputs as follows:

```
<input name="option[][<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[][<?php echo $cmd2; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[][<?php echo $cmd3; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[][<?php echo $cmd4; ?>]" type="text">
[..]
```

There is an undefined amount of inputs, each time.

When the form is submitted I want to save the value of "option[]" into a javascript array (I am using AJAX so the state of the array will not get deleted).

I have tried to achieve this with `$('form').serializeArray()` in my AJAX request, but I am not sure how I can access only the "option[]" data.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what result to you expect? an array containing all inputs' (with name `option`) values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.push()`
.push() is a function that adds an element on the end of the array and expands the array respectively.
http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/

```
var myarray = []; //  new Array()
myarray.push($("#inputid").val());
```

to push all input value (in your form)  to array

```
var myarray = [];
$('#form').find(':input').each(function(){
  myarray.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as I said in my question, I have an undefined amount of inputs so I cannot assign them IDs

Comment: @Ronnyvdb The two code samples are independent. The second one will get any `input` inside the `#form` element and push their values into an array. Give your form an ID of `form` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, it's worth pointing out that (assuming you perform this action at the appropriate time, or following the appropriate event) this can be done in two relatively simple ways.

With jQuery:

```
var options = $('input[name^="option"]').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
```

Or with plain JavaScript (modern browser):

```
var options = [].map.call[document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="option"]'), function(a){
    return this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if your `HTML` is `option[<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]` instead of `option[][<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]` like,

```
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd2; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd3; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd4; ?>]" type="text">
```

Comment: Hi, I have change the code to what you suggested, now how can I access the option array when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Just use classes, like this:

```
<input class="option" name="option[<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]" type="text">
<input class="option" name="option[<?php echo $cmd2; ?>]" type="text">

var options = [];
$('.option').each(function(){
  options.push($(this).val());
});
```

Or match by `name` attribute directly:

```
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd1; ?>]" type="text">
<input name="option[<?php echo $cmd2; ?>]" type="text">

var options = [];
$("input[name*='option']").each(function(){
  options.push($(this).val());
});
```